# Проблема с отрисовкой текста из TextBox на Bitmap

Tags: c#

Добрый день! Я пишу свой графический редактор. Сейчас нахожусь на стадии разработки инструмента текст. Использую контрол `TextBox` для записи текста. И я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: когда перерисовываю текст с текстбокса на `bitmap`, то он немного смещается в зависимости от шрифта. Вот та часть кода:

```
var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

g.DrawString(textBox.Text, textBox.Font, new SolidBrush(textBox.ForeColor), textBox.Location);
```

Можете подсказать, как решить данную задачу? Чтобы текст отрисовывался на том же месте, где он и находился в `textBox`. Также пробовал использовать `label` и с него отрисовывать на `bitmap`, но проблема не уходит. Все также, немного, да смещается.

Пробовал через Textrender.DrawText, но текст все равно смещается. Приведу пример для Label. Делал все в методе `PictureBox.OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)`. Ниже два куска кода:

1)

```
label.Visible = false;

TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, label.Text, label.Font, label.Location, label.ForeColor);
```

2)

```
label.Visible = false;

var bitmap = new Bitmap(pictureBox.Width, pictureBox.Height);

var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

TextRenderer.DrawText(g, label.Text, label.Font, label.Location, label.ForeColor);

e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
```

Т.е. в первом случае рисую на самом pictureBox, во втором - на bitmap, который потом отрисовываю на pictureBox.

Могу заметить, что строчку:

```
label.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
```

можно не писать, т.к. что присваивай true, что false - результат один и тот же в моем случае (хоть и непонятно почему)

`label.Visible = false;` - писал для того, чтобы она не отображалась на pictureBox, когда мы уже отрисовали текст.

Ниже прикладываю три картинки:

1 - изначально как выглядит label на pictureBox,

2 - как при отрисовке на pictureBox,

3 - как при отрисовке на bitmap.

На них отчетливо видно, что текст перемещается. Причем, в случае с битмапом, шрифт еще и полужирным стал почему-то.

[image: label, pictureBox, bitmap]

Comment: проверьте отступы текстбокса

Comment: Как? + текст рисуется не только чуть правее или левее, но еще и выше/ниже

Comment: в настройках текстбокса

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `TextRenderer.DrawText`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Увы, но пока еще проблема не решена

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первых версиях дотнета для прорисовки текста использовалась технология GDI+, метод `Graphics.DrawString`. Потом, с версии .NET 2.0, прорисовка текста в целях улучшения качества и производительности была переведена на GDI - метод [TextRenderer.DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Настройка по умолчанию для всего проекта задаётся в файле Program.cs. Там должна быть строка

```
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
```

Параметр `false` означает использование GDI. [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.application.setcompatibletextrenderingdefault%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

У некоторых контролов, в частности у `Label`, есть свойство [UseCompatibleTextRendering](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.label.usecompatibletextrendering%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), позволяющее задать используемый способ отрисовки.

`TextBox` в современных версиях дотнета тоже использует GDI. Следовательно, чтобы ваша ручная прорисовка в точности совпадала с текстом в нём, следует использовать `TextRenderer.DrawText`.

---

Предлагаю опробовать следующий код:

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();
    this.Size = new Size(1200, 400);
    string text = "Hello world";
    Font font = new Font("Calibri", 20);
    var label = new Label { Parent = this, Text = text, BackColor = Color.LightYellow, AutoSize = true, Font = font };

    label.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        label.UseCompatibleTextRendering = !label.UseCompatibleTextRendering;
    };

    this.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        label.Visible = !label.Visible;
    };

    this.Paint += (o, e) =>
    {
        if (label.UseCompatibleTextRendering)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(text, font, new SolidBrush(label.ForeColor), label.Location);
        else
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, text, font, label.Location, label.ForeColor);
    };

    this.MouseWheel += (o, e) =>
    {
        var size = font.Size + e.Delta / 5;
        if (size < 5) size = 5;
        if (size > 200) size = 200;

        font = new Font("Calibri", size);
        this.Refresh();
        label.Font = font;
    };
}
```

Поместить его в конструктор формы.
Для краткости оформил обработчики событий лямбдами.

Запустив приложение, можно пощёлкать по лэйблу - это будет менять его свойство `UseCompatibleTextRendering` - должно быть явно видно, как меняется шрифт.

Щёлкая по форме можно скрывать и показывать label. Прямо под этим лэйблом на форме прорисовывается тот же текст с помощью `TextRenderer.DrawText` или `Graphics.DrawString`, в зависимости от свойства лэйбла. У меня совпадение идеальное в обоих случаях.

Колёсиком мышки можно менять размер шрифта, чтобы лучше проверить - совпадает или нет прорисовка.

---

Проблема Windows Forms в сильной зависимости от DPI системы. У меня Windows 10, все настройки по умолчанию. Однако, я попробовал сейчас менять масштаб, отключал/включал ClearType - во всех случаях прорисовка полностью совпадает.

---

По поводу прорисовки в Bitmap. Тут нужно правильно задать как свойства самого битмапа (разрешение и прочее), так и параметры в методе DrawImage (GraphicsUnit). Тут я пас.

Comment: @Валерий - обновил ответ

Comment: ну да, сейчас отрисовывается на том же месте, за исключением случая, если тыкать по самому label. Там все время текст смещается, но это из-за того, что в это время разные прорисовки срабатывают. Странно, почему у меня криво переносился текст, когда использовал `e.Graphics`. Потом пересмотрю свой код. На счет битмапа думаю сделать следующее: перерисовать сначала на pictureBox, а оттуда уже с помощью DrawToBitmap на bitmap. Должно получиться нормально. Вообще, в идеале мне нужно с помощью textBox это делать, попробую попозже поразвлекаться с ним. Спасибо за развернутые ответы