# Отрисовка текста с textBox на pictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Уже затрагивался похожий вопрос ([Проблема с отрисовкой текста из TextBox на Bitmap](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519748/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-textbox-%D0%BD%D0%B0-bitmap)), но там в итоге был написан код для `label`. Думал, что может быть все-таки удастся с помощью `TextRenderer.DrawText`перерисовать текст на то же самое место и для `textBox`, но увы.

Вот код:

```
public Form1()
{
    //InitializeComponent();
    Size = new Size(500, 500);
    var font = new Font("Times New Roman", 20);
    var pictureBox = new PictureBox() { Parent = this, BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight, Size = new Size(300, 300), Location = new Point(50, 50) };
    var textBox = new TextBox { Parent = pictureBox, BackColor = SystemColors.Control, Size = new Size(200, 200), Font = font, Location = new Point(60, 60) };

    pictureBox.MouseDown += (o, e) =>
    {
        textBox.Visible = !textBox.Visible;
    };

    pictureBox.Paint += (o, e) =>
    {
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, textBox.Text, textBox.Font, textBox.Location, textBox.ForeColor);
        //e.Graphics.DrawString(textBox.Text, textBox.Font, new SolidBrush(textBox.ForeColor), textBox.Location);
    };
}
```

А вот результаты, которая выдает программа:

[image: На textBox'e]

[image: Без textBox'a]

Если присмотреться, то видно, что на второй картинке текст поднялся немного выше и правее. Можно непосредственно скопировать код в студию и запустить. Там перемещение куда заметнее происходит. Может кто-нибудь знает, как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `Label`'а по умолчанию нет границы (бордюра). У `TextBox`'а она есть. Естественно, отрисовка текста происходит с учётом отступа на толщину этой границы.

Виды границы задаются перечислением `BorderStyle`. Там три значения: `None`, `FixedSingle`, `Fixed3D`. Получить толщину границы можно из свойств `SystemInformation.BorderSize` и `SystemInformation.Border3DSize`.

Кроме того, для правильной отрисовки нужно указать флаги:

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(graphics, text, font, location, color,
    TextFormatFlags.NoPadding | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
```

Хотя, если зрение мне не изменяет, от второго флага ничего не меняется.

С вычислением координат тоже не всё ладно. При установленном `BorderStyle.Fixed3D` (по умолчанию) должен работать код

```
Point location = Point.Add(textBox.Location, SystemInformation.Border3DSize);
```

Однако, не хватает ещё пикселя.

При бордюре `BorderStyle.FixedSingle` должен работать код

```
Point location = Point.Add(textBox.Location, SystemInformation.BorderSize);
```

Аналогично, не хватает пикселя.
Возможно, что-то подкрутили в современных Виндах.

Comment: я добавил `textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;`, теперь по высоте текст не перемещается, но вправо все равно смещается при отрисовке. Причем если использовать `TextRender.DrawText`, то он сильнее сдвигается вправо, чем при `e.Graphics.DrawString`

Comment: окей, хотя бы спасибо на этом. Пока зеленую галочку ставить не буду, вдруг еще кто-то ответит

Comment: хотя я просто буду тогда смещать location на 1 пиксель по диагонали. Тогда все графически совпадает даже при различных шрифтах. Спасибо

Comment: @Валерий - Да, придётся добавлять по пикселю, хотя идеологически это неправильно.

Comment: @aAlexander Petrov, это да, но что поделать...

Comment: там еще одна бага нашлась. Если у текста задать цвет фона отличный от исходного фона, то ровно на этот пиксель новый фон вылезет за заданные пределы. Пофиксить не смог пока. Вообще похоже на то, что у текста есть какой-то свой недокументированный бордер и падинги. Управлять ими вроде как нечем, разве что запретить падинги совсем, и то только в `TextRenderer`, `DrawString` такое не умеет